# Linux (Ubuntu Gnome 16, Anaconda python 3.5) Cython build error (multiple definitions)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, anaconda, cython

I transfered to Linux from win10. It should be all easy and etc to deal with libs and building on linux... but this simple code do not build. I know how to use cython commands to build (from its tutorial) and it worker in python with msvc=2008, 2013, 2015. But this damn linux is somehow not so nice here ;/ and wont build

helloWorld.pyx

```
#cython: language_level=2
print "hello world!"
```

Or (same error)

helloWorld.pyx

```
#cython: language_level=3
print("hello world!")
```

Im building it with (this ${fileDirname} is from visual code task):

```
zsh -c ". activate py35a && gcc --version && python ${fileDirname}/setup.py build_ext --inplace"
```

setup.py

```
from __init__ import *

try:
    from setuptools import setup
    from setuptools import Extension
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
    from distutils.extension import Extension

from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Compiler.Options import directive_defaults
from Cython.Build import cythonize

import numpy


import os,sys

from sys import platform

path=current_path()
os.chdir(path)

print("CWD: %s"%path)


#this is one of my old functions (like from being a NOOB), it was making error, now I changed it (so it do not add second file with .cpp extension)...
def sources(*lst):
    lst=list(lst)
    for n in range(len(lst)):
        lst[n]+='.pyx'
    return lst


ext_modules=[
    Extension("C_helloWorld",
              sources=sources("helloWorld"),
    ),
]

for extension in ext_modules:
    extension.include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
    extension.language='c++'
    #extension.extra_compile_args=['-g']
    #extension.extra_link_args=['-g', '-pthread']
setup(
        name = 'simple test of cython',
        cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
        ext_modules = ext_modules,

)
```

This is error I get:

```
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
No module named 'adjustText'
CWD: /home/robgrzel/SHARED/GOOGLE/WORKSPACE/PROJECTS/SHIPPING/CTO/A2_CROSS_SECTIONS/
Compiling helloWorld.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing helloWorld.pyx
running build_ext
building 'C_helloWorld' extension
gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/robgrzel/ProgramFiles/Programming/Python/Miniconda3/envs/py35a/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/robgrzel/ProgramFiles/Programming/Python/Miniconda3/envs/py35a/include/python3.5m -c helloWorld.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/helloWorld.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/robgrzel/ProgramFiles/Programming/Python/Miniconda3/envs/py35a/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/robgrzel/ProgramFiles/Programming/Python/Miniconda3/envs/py35a/include/python3.5m -c helloWorld.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/helloWorld.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
g++ -pthread -shared -L/home/robgrzel/ProgramFiles/Programming/Python/Miniconda3/envs/py35a/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/robgrzel/ProgramFiles/Programming/Python/Miniconda3/envs/py35a/lib,--no-as-needed build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/helloWorld.o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/helloWorld.o -L/home/robgrzel/ProgramFiles/Programming/Python/Miniconda3/envs/py35a/lib -lpython3.5m -o /home/robgrzel/SHARED/GOOGLE/WORKSPACE/PROJECTS/SHIPPING/CTO/A2_CROSS_SECTIONS/C_helloWorld.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -pthread
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/helloWorld.o: In function `PyInit_helloWorld':
/home/robgrzel/SHARED/GOOGLE/WORKSPACE/PROJECTS/SHIPPING/CTO/A2_CROSS_SECTIONS/helloWorld.cpp:698: multiple definition of `PyInit_helloWorld'
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/helloWorld.o:/home/robgrzel/SHARED/GOOGLE/WORKSPACE/PROJECTS/SHIPPING/CTO/A2_CROSS_SECTIONS/helloWorld.cpp:698: first defined here
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/helloWorld.o: In function `PyInit_helloWorld':
/home/robgrzel/SHARED/GOOGLE/WORKSPACE/PROJECTS/SHIPPING/CTO/A2_CROSS_SECTIONS/helloWorld.cpp:698: multiple definition of `__pyx_module_is_main_CTO__A2_CROSS_SECTIONS__helloWorld'
build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/helloWorld.o:/home/robgrzel/SHARED/GOOGLE/WORKSPACE/PROJECTS/SHIPPING/CTO/A2_CROSS_SECTIONS/helloWorld.cpp:698: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'g++' failed with exit status 1
```

Solved by changing function sources( it appears, that I was totally my error, not connected with linux and cython, shame me ;/)

Now it gives:

```
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)]
No module named 'adjustText'
CWD: /home/robgrzel/SHARED/GOOGLE/WORKSPACE/PROJECTS/SHIPPING/CTO/A2_CROSS_SECTIONS/
Compiling hello_world.pyx because it changed.
[1/1] Cythonizing hello_world.pyx
running build_ext
building 'c_hello_world' extension
gcc -pthread -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/home/robgrzel/ProgramFiles/Programming/Python/Miniconda3/envs/py35a/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/home/robgrzel/ProgramFiles/Programming/Python/Miniconda3/envs/py35a/include/python3.5m -c hello_world.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/hello_world.o
gcc -pthread -shared -L/home/robgrzel/ProgramFiles/Programming/Python/Miniconda3/envs/py35a/lib -Wl,-rpath=/home/robgrzel/ProgramFiles/Programming/Python/Miniconda3/envs/py35a/lib,--no-as-needed build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/hello_world.o -L/home/robgrzel/ProgramFiles/Programming/Python/Miniconda3/envs/py35a/lib -lpython3.5m -o /home/robgrzel/SHARED/GOOGLE/WORKSPACE/PROJECTS/SHIPPING/CTO/A2_CROSS_SECTIONS/c_hello_world.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -pthread
```

Tada... But this extension name is bad: c_hello_world.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so

Comment: What is `sources("helloWorld")`? This bit looks unusual to me and I can't see a definition of `sources` anywhere. If you look at the link line it lists `build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/helloWorld.o` twice, which is probably why you're getting multiple definitions. But I don't know why it's there twice.

Comment: I do notice it too, but why it happens? And "sources" is kwarg for Extension? If You put "helloWorld.pyx" to sources and... Damn here it was. Its some old function from year ago... Its only one way to describe this what I fell now.. http://s2.quickmeme.com/img/26/2604c8c350d537bb08322a3ea7a94a0fcf8606b56e39ba1f62301224aa417e84.jpg